# How to write test case for conditional statement

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have below conditional statement, how I can write test case for conditional operator

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {(usersApiSuccess && users.id !== null) ?
                <Dashboard />
                : (users.id === null) &&
                <ErrorPage content="User does not exist" />}
        </>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) with `Jest`

Like this

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  it('renders the Dashboard component if usersApiSuccess is true and users.id is not null', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<SomeComponent usersApiSuccess={true} users={{ id: 1 }} />);
    expect(getByTestId('dashboard')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('renders the ErrorPage component if usersApiSuccess is true and users.id is null', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<SomeComponent usersApiSuccess={true} users={{ id: null }} />);
    expect(getByText('User does not exist')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('does not render any component if usersApiSuccess is false', () => {
    const { queryByTestId, queryByText } = render(<SomeComponent usersApiSuccess={false} users={{ id: 1 }} />);
    expect(queryByTestId('dashboard')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(queryByText('User does not exist')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

[For Reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/write-unit-tests-using-react-testing-library/)